# JQuery form plugin sending empty data to Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

html form:

```
<form id="importForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <p>
                            <label for="ownerName">Owner Name<pow
                                    class="requiredFormItem">&nbsp;*</pow></label><select id="ownerName"
                                name="ownerName"></select>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="policyName">Policy Name<pow
                                    class="requiredFormItem">&nbsp;*</pow></label><select id="policyName"
                                name="policyName"></select>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="partition">Custom Partition Name</label> <input
                                type="text" name="partition" id="partition" class="textField" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <pow class="requiredFormItem">*&nbsp;</pow>
                            Required Fields
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" id="importCampaignButton" class="submit"
                                value="Import" />
                        </p>
                    </form>
```

javascript:

```
function importObject(){
var options = {
        target: '#importForm',
        type: 'POST',
        url: hostServer + '/import',
        beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
        success: function () {
            displayMessageDialog("File imported successfully", true);
        },
        error: function(e){
            displayMessageDialog("An AJAX error occured. " + JSON.stringify(e));
        }
};
$('#importForm').ajaxForm(options);
//$('#importForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
}

function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
var queryString = $.param(formData);
alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
return true;
}

$(function() {
    importObject();
});
```

when clicked submit it tells me:

```
 About to submit: ownerName=161&policyName=Global+Policy&partition=
```

On node.js:

I'm listening for a post at the URL...

```
app.post('/import', campaigns.importCampaign2);
```

and printing...

```
exports.importCampaign2 = function (request, response){
utilities.debugLog('Import campaign...');
utilities.debugLog('request files? ' + request.files);
utilities.debugLog('request body? ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
utilities.debugLog('request params? ' + JSON.stringify(request.params));
utilities.debugLog('request query? ' + JSON.stringify(request.query));
```

But I seem to be getting nothing...

```
request files? undefined
request body? {}
request params? {}
request query? {}
```

I'm trying to make a form with a file upload, but it has to be compatible with IE 9 so I can't use html5. JQuery form plugin works if I do ajaxSubmit(options), however the file returned is... a string '[file Object]' and a body parameter, not files parameter... The speculation was the form HAD to send, so I'm trying this other way in the hope it will send the actual file. But it's not sending anything anymore...

app.js setup:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3333);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', {layout: false});
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
app.use(require('body-parser')({ keepExtensions: true}));
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'mySecret', store: new MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 600000}) }));
app.use(require('method-override')());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
next();
});
```

@mscdex Interesting! It does send something! Disabling body-parser would be a real hassle but with it on I saw my values:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryJo01BR3yUDBh094k
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ownerName"

161
------WebKitFormBoundaryJo01BR3yUDBh094k
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policyName"

Global Policy
------WebKitFormBoundaryJo01BR3yUDBh094k
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="partition"


------WebKitFormBoundaryJo01BR3yUDBh094k--
```

Comment: If you dump the contents of the request (`request.on('data', function(d){ console.log(d.toString()); });`) with the body parser middleware disabled, what does the output look like?

Comment: Post your `app.use()` section, you probably don't have bodyparser included.

Comment: BodyParser is only necessary when you use files. am I wrong?

Comment: edited original comment. @mscdex

Comment: @Dalorzo Actually, in Express 4 the external `body-parser` module only supports application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded now, so you will have to separately use another module for multipart/form-data handling. But you can have multipart forms without files.

Comment: So that is your problem @user997739, you need to use a multipart parsing module for multipart/form-data requests now with Express 4. Some examples of such modules are: [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy)(/[connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy)/[multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer)/[reformed](https://www.npmjs.org/package/reformed)) and [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a multipart parsing module for multipart/form-data requests now with Express 4. Some examples of such modules are: [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy)(/[connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy)/[multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer)/[reformed](https://www.npmjs.org/package/reformed)) and [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable).

The reason is in Express 4, the bodyParser() middleware was extracted into its own module ([body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser)) but that new module only supports application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded now, so you have to separately use another module for multipart/form-data handling.

Comment: Thankyou. Trying this now will get back and say if it worked.

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. Thankyou SO much. Been at this for a day and a half.

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved the same problem with the post ..
http://www.componentix.com/blog/9/file-uploads-using-nodejs-now-for-real